# Flattened records to parent/child objects using LINQ. Without duplication of data

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to better understand grouping using LINQ. I would like to take a collection of flattened records and convert them into two object collections in a parent/child relationship. In my example the flattened records are contained in ImportedExpenses class while the Expense/ExpenseLineItem classes form the parent/child relationship respectively.

```
public class ImportedExpense {
    public string EmployeeName {get; set;}
    public string CustomerName {get; set;}
    public DateTime ExpenseDate {get; set;}
    public Decimal Amount {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
}

public class Expense {
    public string EmployeeName {get; set;}
    public string CustomerName {get; set;}
    public List<ExpenseLineItem> LineItems {get; set;}
}

public class ExpenseLineItem {
    public DateTime ExpenseDate {get; set;}
    public Decimal Amount {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
}
```

In the past I have accomplished this by repeating information in the ExpenseLineItem class.

```
public class ExpenseLineItem {
    public string EmployeeName {get; set;}
    public string CustomerName {get; set;}
    public DateTime ExpenseDate {get; set;}
    public Decimal Amount {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
}
```

and I would use the following LINQ statement where `importedData` is a collection of type `ImportedExpense`

```
var expenseCollection = importedData.GroupBy(x => 
    new 
    {
        x.EmployeeName,
        x.CustomerName
    })
    .Select (y => new Expense()
    {
        EmployeeName = y.Key.EmployeeName,
        CustomerName = y.Key.CustomerName,
        LineItems = y.ToList();
    });
```

However, I would like to accomplish the same thing without having to repeat information in the Expense and ExpenseItem class.

How would I form the LINQ query to accomplish this? If possible with the fluent syntax as I am more familiar with it vs the query syntax.

Comment: `ImportredExpenses` is a collection of the type `ImportedExpense`. Sorry for the confusion I have updated the example to use `importedData` as the variable name

Comment: What is the type for this field/variable ?

Comment: there seems to be a lot of mistakes in your code...  you have two weird groupbys, and you don't transform your lineitems into ExpenseLineItem   also, seems unclear about what you are converned with?

Comment: I honestly don't understand what being repeated?

Comment: Sorry about that. Some copy paste errors while I developed the example. I have corrected them.

Comment: The repeated info is that the `ExpenseLineItem` class contains properties that should really only belong to the `Expense` class. I would like `EmployeeName` and 
 `CustomerName` to be in the `Expense` class

Comment: Still find this question strange this code will produce a compile time error. Unless importedData is ExpenseLineItem you can do inner select before to list to exclude stuff you don't need?

Comment: To me the `ExpenseLineItem` class should not contain the `EmployeeName` or `CustomerName` properties. Yet it is only with this type of structure that I can get the LINQ statement to work.

Comment: Related: [How to build a hierarchy with use Linq to object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592147/how-to-build-a-hierarchy-with-use-linq-to-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I have understood your question right, but if you want to transform `ImportedExpense` to an hierarchy of `Expense->ExpenseLineItem`, you are almost there with your code. Try this:

```
var expenseCollection = importedData.GroupBy(x => 
    new 
    {
        x.EmployeeName,
        x.CustomerName
    })
    .Select (y => new Expense()
    {
        EmployeeName = y.Key.EmployeeName,
        CustomerName = y.Key.CustomerName,
        LineItems = y.Select(ie => new ExpenseLineItem()
        {
            ExpenseDate = ie.ExpenseDate,
            Amount = ie.Amount,
            Description = ie.Description
        }).ToList();
    });
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `GroupBy` extension that lets you do a projection of the grouped items.  You can use this to project `ExpenseLineItem`s grouped by the anonymous type with the other data points in it.

In code it looks like this:

```
var expenseCollection = importedData
    .GroupBy
    (
        x => new { x.EmployeeName, x.CustomerName },
        x => new ExpenseLineItem
        {
            ExpenseDate = x.ExpenseDate,
            Amount = x.Amount,
            Description = x.Description
        }
    )
    .Select
    (
        y => new Expense
        {
            EmployeeName = y.Key.EmployeeName,
            CustomerName = y.Key.CustomerName,
            LineItems = y.ToList()
        }
    );
```

Alternatively you can do the projection in the select:

```
var expenseCollection = importedData
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.EmployeeName, x.CustomerName })
    .Select
    (
        y => new Expense
        {
            EmployeeName = y.Key.EmployeeName,
            CustomerName = y.Key.CustomerName,
            LineItems = y.Select
            (
                item => new ExpenseLineItem
                {
                    ExpenseDate = item.ExpenseDate,
                    Amount = item.Amount,
                    Description = item.Description
                }
            ).ToList()
        }
    );
```

You could move the projection out to a separate method or a cast operator, but I think the above is nicely transparent.